# Delegate is nil when passing data back to VC

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my example usage of delegate programmatically. The code passes a message from one view to other view controller. I have two view SendMessageController and Receive message controller. It's passing data back scenario.

Protocol is defined in SendMessageController.

```
protocol SendMessageDelegate: AnyObject {
    func message(text: String)
}
final class SendMessageController: UIViewController {         
    weak var delegate: SendMessageDelegate?          

    @objc func button() {
        sendMessage()  
    }

    func sendMessage() {
       let message = “Hello World”
       delegate?.message(text: message)
       print("Delegate is :\(delegate)")
       print("self:\(self)")   
}
```

In Show Message View Controller which receives message:

```
final class ShowMessageController: UIViewController,SendMessageDelegate {
     
    let sendMessageController = SendMessageController() 
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sendMessageController.delegate = self
        print("\(sendMessageController)")
    }
    
    func message(text: String) {
        print(“The message is:\(text)”)              
    }       
}
```

The delegates prints nil, and memory address of *print(self)* is different than *print("(sendMessageController)")*.
I had use delegate before where memory adress of SendVC were same, don't know what is happening here.

Comment: I think your code works fine. Is it possible if your delegate to be called before viewDidLoad on `ShowMessageController`? Btw, you always need to override viewDidLoad with super.

Comment: show the code for presenting `SendMessageController`. It seems you are not calling the correct instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a brand new instance when you call

```
let sendMessageController = SendMessageController()
```

This instance is not the one that storyboard creates using **segue**. So you ended up having two separate `SendMessageController`:

- One have correct delegate, but not visible for user actions
- One is visible but not linked to the correct delegate

You should try to get the correct instance from the storyboard instead of creating a new one like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? SendMessageController {
        nextViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

<sub>⚠️ Since there is no-code to present the `sendMessageController` in your samples, it seems like you are using storyboard. Even if you are not, the issue is the same, but there should be a different way to get the correct instance.</sub>

Comment: Yes, the problem was there, I created new instance when presenting controller and re-declared again. Shame I have repeated this already.  :

Thank you for your input. It solved me.

`
    @objc func confirmButtonClicked(){

      let sendMessageController = SendMessageController()

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sendMessageController, animated: true)
        
    }`